# CS106A handout 6 Exception java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

Got an Error with NullPointerException . (cs106A handout 6 - Name Count using hash map)
Debugger told me  the problem located @ String input variable. I got no idea how to solve it. 
thanks for reading.

```
import acm.io.*;
import acm.program.*;
import acm.util.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.io.BufferedReader.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class NameCounts extends ConsoleProgram{
// hashmap 
static HashMap<String,Integer> myUniq = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
static String input ;

static public void insertName(){

    try {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    while(true){
        System.out.println("Enter name:");

               // if keyboard input contain new unique name , 
               // store it in the hashmap and count the value +1
        input = br.readLine();
        if(input.equals("")) break;
        if( myUniq.containsKey(input) ==false){
            Integer temp = myUniq.get(input);
            temp = temp + 1;
            myUniq.put(input,temp);
        }

      }
    }
    catch (IOException e){ };
}
    // print and show every single hash map and count value
    static public void releaseUnique(){
            for(int i= 1 ; i < myUniq.size() ; i++){
    System.out.println("Entry"+"[" + input + "]"+"has count"+myUniq.get(input));        
            }
}

public static void main (String[] args){
    insertName();
    releaseUnique();
    }
}
```

[image: errorlog]

Comment: you don't have to write your course and handout name, and also post your logcat output

Comment: Please add the exception stacktrace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should change

```
if( myUniq.containsKey(input) ==false){
    Integer temp = myUniq.get(input);
    temp = temp + 1;
    myUniq.put(input,temp);
}
```

to

```
if(myUniq.containsKey(input)) {
    Integer temp = myUniq.get(input);
    temp = temp + 1;
    myUniq.put(input, temp);
} else {
    myUniq.put(input, 1);
}
```

Comment: Wow thats amazing . So the HashMap didnt auto-initialise the Int Value   as 0 like what INT does.  Thanks for enlighten me.